# Can Node js redirect to a url and display it in another new browser?

Tags: node.js

I want to use node js redirect to the url and display the url in a new browser, can that be happening?

Comment: What you need is browser's javascript, not node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node Js is a server side technology which can redirect the browsers request to a new location but cannot instructed the browser to open a new window.

You need to use client side javascript to ask the browser to open another window see here:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

or use target="_blank" within the link itself.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this cross browser is to use the "open" npm module
This module allows you to open a new browser window and designate a url to go to

`npm install open --save`

then in your request when you want to open the new browser and load the url simply call

```
open( 'http://urltodirect.to', function (err) {
  if ( err ) throw err;    
});
```

That will open a new browser window and send the tab to `http://urltodirect.to`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect to a new URL with Node as part of a server request if you use the [Express framework's redirect method](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect).

However you can't display the URL in a new browser with Node, as this is front-end work. You could use `target=_blank` within your HTML link in order to do this.

Answer (score 1):

One small trick that works for is,
I have a redirect on the link which I want to open in a new tab.

And added **`target="_blank"`** in my form

```
<form method='post' action="/post/URL" target="_blank">
...
</form>
```

Comment: Nice one! Almost forgot about its existence for form elements.